# CodeName One, Action event not working- need explanation

Tags: java, mobile, user-interface, codenameone

I'm trying to get and action event to fire on my HelloWorld. im using the GUI and when it auto creates the:

```
protected void onMain_Button1Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code
    super.onMain_Button1Action(c,event);    
}
```

I know its not going to work because there is no void of the same type in the superclass.

```
protected void onMain_Button1Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code
    Dialog.show("Test", "it works", "OK",null);
}
```

And I'm still getting nothing. I've looked for other tutorials on how to use codenames as one but i cant find any. And I dont get the one made by the author. if any one can toss me a line i would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the resource file in the designer and NOT delete the call to super. If you are using Eclipse you should refresh the project after saving in the designer using F5.