# CodeName One, Action event not created normally - need explanation

Tags: events, netbeans, handler, codenameone

Good morning, Everyone.

I have a simple Hello World application created from basic "Hello World" template.
I've added simple button on the main form (in a CodeNameOne GUI designer) and I'm trying to fire an action event by clicking "Action Event". I am saving GUI designer contains before to make an event as it described here - [CodeName One, Action event not working- need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927748/codename-one-action-event-not-working-need-explanation)

But GUI designer ask me to choose some filename instead to simply auto-create an event handler in NetBeans IDE as it shown in every manual. The main problem - I can not to select any file in this window. I don't know which file types GUI Designer need, but all *.java files from my projects are gray in this window and not accessible accordingly.

Event handler is created too in "StateMachine.java", but not always. 
For example, event handler created for button, but not created for Tabs.

Mac OS version is 10.8.3 (under Oracle Virtual Box)
NetBeans IDE is 7.3 and Java version is 1.6.0_43

Help me, please, this project is very nice, 
but I can not continue to develop my application while this problem not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases NetBeans install isn't detected correctly by the plugin. You need to point at the NetBeans.app file not at the source file. You can force this by selecting the menu option "File->Setup NetBeans".

This is a known issue in the issue tracker with several artifacts e.g.: http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=611&start=100 once you pick the right copy of NetBeans this should "just work".